# Remote control Windows machine via Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, remote-desktop, remote-control

Are there any tools available (preferably standard tools that usually come together with the OS) that would allow me to control my windows-machine, from my ubuntu-machine, via command line (IE. I only have access to command-line on my ubuntu)?

**EDIT:** To clarify a bit about what my scenario looks like:

I have three computers; A, B and C.

- **A**: I have access to this one, it is running Ubuntu Linux.
- **B**: Since I dont know the public IP-address of this computer, I dont have access to it. A, on the other hand, sits in the same local network with a DNS, and I **do** know the name on this computer (for example, I can ping B by accessing A remotely ("ping b.company.loc"), but that only reveales the **local** IP-address of B).
- **C**: Is the computer I want to use to access B remotely.

So I ask again: Does anyone know any way for me to access B, from C or A, without installing anything on B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the new details,

You have very limited options without having some kind of server on B that would let you connect.

You can connect from C to A which is a very good start. From there you can scan B for open ports using nmap (usage: `nmap hostname`)

If you have ports open like 22 (ssh), 23 (telnet), 3389 (Remote Desktop), or 5900 (VNC), then your in luck. You can use port forwarding to bind a port from B onto A and access it from C.

[This serverfault thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/229323/how-do-i-vnc-using-a-ssh-tunnel-from-one-ubuntu-box-into-another/229365#229365) goes through the process for VNC. The "localhost:5900" would have to be changed to its corresponding protocol ("localhost:3389" for RDP) and opened up in the corresponding program (mstsc.exe for RDP).

If there are no ports open on B for remote access, then you are probably out of luck. If there are other open ports for other services, you can still try hacking it using [Metasploit](http://www.metasploit.com/) from the Ubuntu system.

Answer (score 3):

You could install the telnet server that is provided by Microsoft. You would need to go to Add/Remove programs (XP) or Programs and Features (vista/7) and then click on "Turn windows features on or off". From there select Telnet Server. You might need the windows installation disk.

Once you have the ports open in the windows firewall, you should be able to telnet from your Ubuntu system to your windows system.

[image]

Telnet is not considered secure. I think it sends the username and password across the network in plain text. If you want something more secure, you can use the SSH server in [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).

Comment: Although this would be a very good answer on its own, unfortunately it does not cover my particular case, as I have no physical access _at all_ to the machine running windows.